# Pass variable value to --include argument using grep command inside bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

I want to pass to grep command (inside a bash script), the file extensions to search, using --include argument.
These file extensions will be entered by user from command line as an argument (4th argument holds files extensions, in a comma separated way).

This is my script:

```
...
echo "Searching in ${4} files for pattern"
egrep -irn . --include=\*.{"${4}"} --exclude=\*.{class} -e "${3}"
...
```

I also tried creating a String with the command, and calling eval, like this:

```
...
comando="egrep -irn . --include="\\*.{${4}}" --exclude=\*.{class} -e "${3}""
echo $comando
resultado=eval $comando
echo $resultado
```

(when echoing comando i get this:  *egrep -irn . --include=*.{wsdl,xml} --exclude=*.{class} -e texto* , which is exactly the commando that if executed in command line returns some matches.)

I also tried passing a variable with all the include argument:

```
...
argumento="\\*.{${4}}"
egrep -irn . --include=$argumento --exclude=\*.{class} -e "${3}"
...
```

This is how the script is called from command line:

sh ./searchRecursiveIterativeEgrep.sh /tmp/test/another/ /usr/local/aux/ "texto" wsdl,xml

Any ideas on how to achieve this?
Thank you

Comment: The UNIX tool to find files is appropriately named `find`, not `grep`. Forget you ever saw GNU greps options for finding files as adding them was a terrible idea (whats next - grep options to sort the output?) and just use `find` to find files and `grep` to **G**lobally search for a **R**egular **E**xpression in a file and **P**rint the matching text. Your life will be much simpler.

Comment: I am trying to find a Regular Expression in files, so I need grep. The command works as expected, but I can't make it work with arguments from command line.

Comment: a) grep is not the only tool that can find regular expressions in files and b) I'm not suggesting you don't use grep to find regular expressions in files, I'm suggesting you don't use grep to find the files as it's the wrong approach and is making your grep command ridiculously complicated. Use `find` to find the files and `grep` (or other tool) to search for regexps within the files that `find` finds. Something along the lines of `find . -name '*.extension' -print0 | xargs -0 grep 'regexp'`.

Comment: I did not provide all my script details. I use find to find files, and then use grep to find the pattern in those found files

Comment: Then why are you also using grep to find files (-r, --include, --exclude)? Simply never use those arguments, they were added counter to the UNIX philosophy of having each tool do one job and do it well - just use the tools designed for each job. You're already experiencing the pain of not doing that. There's really nothing else I can say but - good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I just understood why you had a problem: If I copy/paste the generated command, it works but within a shell it doesn't.

So I propose that as a workaround

```
argumento="\\*.{${4}}"
echo egrep -irn . --include=$argumento --exclude=\*.{class} -e "${3}" | sh
```

(piping the echo to a new shell does it: it works). Maybe it's not the best answer but it does the job.

Maybe someone can explain that, or come out with a better, cleaner answer.

Comment: This command works in command line with multiple extension. egrep -irn . --include=\*.{wsdl,xml} --exclude=\*.{class} -e texto

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide any sample input or expected output so this is obviously untested but the right approach is to use `find` to **FIND** files and `grep` to **G**lobally search for a **R**egular **E**xpression in a file and **P**rint the matching text (see the hints in their names ;-) ). Something like:

```
find . -type f -name "*.$4" -print0 | xargs -0 grep -Ein "$3"
```

man find, xargs, and grep for details.